# Enabling DriveTime (Minutes) in Network Analyst Service Area Creation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 Network Analyst Extension to try and do a drive time analysis for fire station service areas.

Using [this tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/network-analyst-tutorial.pdf) I am going through step by step to make this happen, however, I am unable to create the analysis using drive time as an impedance and can only choose distance as an option:

[image]

My road network dataset has a field that shows the time it would take to traverse the segment at 40mph.

How do I enable DriveTime as an option in my analysis settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Network Dataset requires the Cost/Attribute in the **Function Evaluator** (when building your network)

[image]

You can see here there are 4 types of attribute (`Minutes` will build your drive time analysis buffers)

[image]

See
**Types of evaluators used by a network**

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Types_of_evaluators_used_by_a_network/00470000000n000000/